# Machine Learning in Action, python code in chapter 2

Tags: python, debugging

I currently read this book, machine learning in action but I cannot understand some codes in this book, chapter 2 (kNN).

```
def file2matrix(file):
    fr=open(file)
    numofLines=len(fr.readlines())
    returnMat=zeros((numofLines,3))
    classLabelVector=[]
    fr=open(file)
```

The first question is, why should I open file twice. When I deleted the second of **fr=open(file)**, there was no data in return. Why should I open(file) twice?

And the second question is about zeros. When I tried line by line in iPython, iPython said that name 'zeros' is not defined. Of course, import numpy and numpy.zeros will work but in this code, there is no 'numpy', but it works. Why it works? I cannot understand this. Give me an answer please!

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't open the file twice.  I think what the author meant (assuming you copied the code correctly), was to close the file perhaps with `fr.close()`.

Secondly, you're right, at least in the snippet you've shared `zeros` is not defined anywhere and so you'll need a `from numpy import zeros` or similar.

Lastly, why do you say this code works?  Are you running this code alongside anything else?  Perhaps your IPython session as some state loaded that, for example, defines `zeros`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. First thing, the code is right and there is no typo, and I'm sure that is right because without that, full code doesn't work. You can download the full code in here: https://www.manning.com/books/machine-learning-in-action
And regarding the second thing, at the very first line in the full code, author import numpy and that's it (not defining zeros). And this code I wrote is just one part of the full code and that works (I tried, of course) surprisingly.